# Transfer recording per minute to aws S3 from twilio recording logs on the time the call is going on, not when the call has ended

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, twilio, aws-lambda

i had a doubt that can i transfer the recording from twilio rest api logs to the AWS S3 . I searched a lot and got to know that we can transfer the recording from twilio recording to AWS S3 but only when the call is over, but when the call is going on cant we transfer the data at the same time to AWS S3 at a minute interval . Can this be acheived by any method ?

Answer (score 0):

The question doesn't really seem to be related to S3 as much as to Twilio.  Until Twilio notifies you at your specified [`recordingStatusCallback`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/record#attributes-recording-status-callback) that the recording is ready, you don't have access to the recording.  This feature appears to be limited to downloading, not streaming.

Assuming Twilio had a way to stream the file to you, there would still be a problem with what it sounds like you want, because transferring the data to S3 at 1 minute intervals wouldn't serve a meaningful purpose, unless you were for some reason uploading multiple files that were each 1 minute long... because while you are uploading a file to S3, that new file is not available for download from S3.

Uploads to S3 are *atomic*, which means that until the upload finishes, the file does not exist and can't be downloaded.  If an upload to S3 is an overwrite of an existing object, the *old* version will be downloaded until the new upload is complete, sometimes a little longer.  S3 does not expose a file that has not yet finished uploading.

Comment: yeah twilio was the main component over here in this case . lets assume i just have to store the data in the S3 and not to download it , what if the interval is increased from 1 minute to 5 minute as , what i was trying to do is to get the recording from twilio every 5 minutes and then save the file first to aws lambda's  "/tmp"  folder and then send into s3 and name the file as per numbers and all these code meant to be written in my aws lambda . It this possible enough to implement ?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The only way you could achieve this with Twilio, that I know of, is to make the Twilio side of the call a [conference](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/conference) as well and [generate a call](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls) once a minute that dials into the Twilio conference to record it and then hang up after a minute to be replaced by a new call. That way you can get recordings by the minute, you just have to do the work to make that happen. You would also need to detect the end of the conference on the other side so that you don't carry on recording forever.